# Different lighting when performing bool

Tags: cycles-render-engine, boolean-modifier

I have a GTX 1660 Ti, and a RTX 3060 laptop gpu.

I have a scene with a bool, render with cycles.
Removing the bool, seems to result in same renders, however with the beautiful bool active, I get completely different results.

Here is the scene file:
[image]

Edit: Turns out it is not the different gpus. Each time I open the file it is either bright, or dull with a roughly 50% chance.
As I render with deadline it does indeed keep opening the file often.

Edit 2: Just keep an activating and deactivating the bool, this alone triggers the bizzare effect.

But with the bool active I get this result on the 1660 ti.
[image]

And this result on my RTX 3060
[image]

Therefore my tiny sad renderfarm produces quiet a lot of flickering.